# Remove inner query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

We have a SQL query which is not written as per the sql guideline. We have to change the query but if we change the logic and remove the inner query then it take to much time to execute. Below is the query:

```
 select col1,
         col2,
         case
             when col1 <> '' then(select top 1
                                   col1
                                   from table1 as BP
                                   where bp.col1 = FD.col1 order by BP.col1)
             when col2 <> '' then(select top 1
                                     BP.col2
                                    from table1 as BP
                                    where BP.col2 = FD.col2 order by BP.col2)
             else ''
         end
  from table2 FD
```

The above query is being used to insert the data into a temp table. The table1 has almost 100 million of data. Is there any way to remove the inline query along with the good performance. We have already created the indexes on table1. Any thought?

Comment: why you need to remove inline sql?

Comment: Table1 has 100 million of data but what about Table2 ?

Comment: I can not understand why do you need subqueries since it returns `col1 and col2` from outer table `table2`

Comment: You should show us sample data here.  The subqueries don't make complete sense, because you are arbitrarily retaining a single record.

Comment: Yes. Table1 has million of data along with type. We are fetching the type from table1.

Comment: Previously we have used the inner join with table1 and table2 but it is taking too much time.

Comment: What does the table structure look like, and what are the PK constraints?

Comment: Without digging into to it too much I would try to outer apply the nested SQL that is normally much quicker and looks nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY COALESCE(T2.col1,T2.col2)),
    T2.col1,
    T2.col2,
    T1Val = COALESCE(T2.col1,T2.col2,'')
    FROM table2 T2
       LEFT JOIN table1 T1
          ON
          (
             (
                ISNULL(T2.col1,'')<>'' AND T1.col1 = T2.col1
             )
             OR
             (
                ISNULL(T2.col2,'')<>'' AND T1.col2 = T2.col2
             )
          )
)
SELECT
    *
    FROM CTE
       WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: CTE will 100 million of records, I think performance will be hit hard.

Comment: but it's a better approach than taking top 1 in the inner query

Answer (score 0):

Here is my modest help:

1. You can already prepare and materialize your subquery1 and subquery2 (Group BY col1 or col2) <-- It will reduce the size of your table 1)
2. Split your main query (from table2 into 3 different queries)

   - 1 with `SELECT .. FROM table2 WHERE col1 <> ''`
   - 1 with `SELECT .. FROM table2 WHERE col1 = '' AND col2 <> ''`
   - 1 with `SELECT .. FROM table2 WHERE col1 = '' AND col2 = ''`
     Use an `INNER JOIN` with your table created in the first point.
     (If you use SSIS you can // and use your inner join table into a Lookup)
3. If your col1 or col2 use a NVARCHAR(MAX) or a big size, you should have a look to a HashFunction (MD5 for example) and compare Hash instead.
4. Be sure to have all your indexes

At least if it is not performant, you can try with:
`OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 .. )`

Another idea should be:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col1 AS yourNewCol 
  FROM table2 T2
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM table1 T1 WHERE T1.col1 = T2.col1)

UNION ALL

SELECT col1, col2, col2 AS yourNewCol 
  FROM table2 T2
 WHERE 
      NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM table1 T1 WHERE T1.col1 = T2.col1)
  AND EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM table1 T1 WHERE T1.col2 = T2.col2)

UNION ALL

...
```

I don't have a clean solution for you, but some ideas.
Let me know if it helps you.

Regards,
Arnaud